# « Le record du monde de vitesse à ski » : choix de la préposition et accord ?

Tags: prépositions, pluriel, sport, fréquence-utilisation, groupe-nominal

> Le Français Simon Billy, 31 ans, s’est emparé du record du monde de
> vitesse **à ski** en atteignant 255,5 km/h mercredi à Vars (Hautes-Alpes),
> a-t-on appris auprès des organisateurs. (via [AFP](https://www.lapresse.ca/sports/sports-d-hiver/2023-03-22/ski-de-vitesse/une-vitesse-record-de-255-5-km-h-pour-le-francais-simon-billy.php))

1. Les prépositions *par, en, sur* et *avec* sont-elles toutes
   possibles ici et quand elles sont possibles y a-t-il des
   contre-indications à l'emploi et pourquoi ?
2. Dans les cas retenus précédemment, peut-on avoir le nom au singulier
   et au pluriel indifféremment ?
3. Quelle combinaison est la plus usuelle/fréquente pour ce genre de
   discipline (*ski de vitesse*) et pense-t-on que la vitesse a une influence sur ce choix
   ?

Answer (score 3):

1. *Vitesse par ski* me semble impossible (faut-il diviser la vitesse par deux ?)
   *Vitesse en ski(s)* s'entend de plus en plus mais est souvent encore considéré comme incorrect avec pour justification qu'on n'est pas à l'intérieur d'un ski ou de skis mais dessus. *Course de vitesse en skis* est néanmoins improbable.
   *Vitesse sur skis* est possible mais rare. Là aussi, *Course de vitesse sur skis* est très peu idiomatique.
   *Vitesse avec skis* n'est pas incorrect mais s'applique mal au contexte. *Course de vitesse avec skis* donne l'impression que le champion court avec des skis sur le dos, ou du moins qu'il est handicapé par ses skis.
2. Le pluriel parait s'imposer avec les deux dernières propositions. Avec *en* comme *à*, le singulier me semble plus courant, par analogie avec la locution figée ***à pied*** toujours au singulier (***course à pied***) même si on n'est pas unijambiste, mais aussi *à cheval*, *à vélo*/*à bicyclette*/*en vélo*, *en voiture*, *en train* où le singulier s'impose naturellement. On dit d'ailleurs *en métro*, *en train*, *en avion* même si on en a pris successivement plusieurs.
3. Quand *ski* est qualifié, la préposition *à* n'est plus aussi courante et peut sonner très mal. *Je suis venu en ski de fond* (ok, mais 3 hits seulement via Google) mais *Je suis venu à ski de fond* est très discutable (0 hits) alors que *Il dévale les pentes à skis nordiques* semble impossible.

Answer (score 1):

- "À ski" est un complément circonstanciel de moyen et désigne l'instrument grâce auquel Simon Billy s'est emparé du record du monde de vitesse.

ou

- "(record de) vitesse à ski" est une expression figée désignant cette discipline, comparable à "saut à ski", "randonnée à ski", etc.

[Edit] ou plutôt comparable à "record de distance à la nage".

Je penche pour la deuxième explication et ne vois pas d'autre possibilité de préposition que "à" dans cette phrase.

Comment: Exact, j'ai édité la réponse. Il n'empêche que pour moi ça reste une expression figée. Avoir un "record du monde de vitesse" tout court et le compléter par "à/en/sur" skis pour préciser la manière dont on s'en est emparé ne me parait pas logique.